# How to remove attributes from the Keycloak JWT access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

By default Keycloak generates the token with following payloads:

```
{
  "jti": "71ac4939-03cb-4ce2-b072-08fa7e1b7f37",
  "exp": 1560239903,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1560239843,
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master",
  "sub": "d3ea1306-f0f9-4b25-b7c5-e64dfbdf949e",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "auth_time": 0,
  "session_state": "0162e8c3-25b3-4fd9-8416-e28bd27b61bd",
  "acr": "1",
  "scope": "email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "admin"
}
```

We can use *protocol mapper* to add custom fields, but is it possible to remove unnecessary fields? For example I do not want **acr**, **email_verified**, **azp**, and etc…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure mappers and client scopes properly. Each scope has its own set of configured protocol mappers, which may add additional claim. E.g. `email` scope by default:

[image]

Keep in the mind: scopes can be also default, so they will be executed implicitly, without explicit definition in the auth request:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jan Garaj. I could eliminate the email_verified and some other fields with the method you mentioned. But the acr and azp are still in token. Is it possible to remove them too?

Comment: @sinaaskarnejad acr/azp might be unnecessary claims for you, but they have technical meaning for used OIDC protocol. I guess you can't disable them.